# How to get a promission on desktop to interactive with IIS7 processing?

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, wcf, iis

I have a WCF (C#) installed on a server that execute xxx.exe file.

The xxx.exe using c++  CreateWindow and write txt file.

I already find a lot of solution ...

[How to execute exe form asp.net ?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1924673.aspx?How%20to%20execute%20exe%20form%20asp%20net%20)

[Unable to Start a Process from ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555134/en-us)

I can start a process from ASP.NET using System.Diagonistics.Process.Start method. Process start in the background ,but I can't see it in the desktop.

I can't find iis admin service and "Allow Service to Interact with Desktop check box" in the services.

Server:

```
Windows 7 64bit
Internet Information Services 7
.NET Framework 4.5
```

WCF:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
Process.Start(@"D:\xxx.exe", "");
```

local services:
[image: where is iis admins]

Comment: Which user's desktop do you want to display the window on? There could be zero, or there could be one, or there could be several.

Comment: i think op means on the server desktop

Comment: Fast User Switching means there could be more than one.

Comment: one connect with one window.

Comment: indeed, @immibis, might be right, you're logged in as yourself and IIS executes under a different user.

Comment: Fast User Switching?? it should not be a problem~~

Comment: 薛龍崎: Alice, Bob and Charlie are logged in with Remote Desktop. Nobody is using the connected mouse and keyboard. Do you want to show the window to Alice, Bob, or Charlie?

Comment: YES, I want show the window. @immibis

Comment: The question was, who do you want to show it to?

Answer (score 1):

go to start, in the search box type "local services", open that program and find IIS Admin Service, click Log On tab there is a radio button group called Log on As and a check box "Allow service to interact with desktop"

You may have to restart service and IIS.

**EDIT:**

If you can't see the Admin Service in local service, then you will have to enable it in Windows Features under Internet Information Services -> Web Management Tools -> IIS6 Management Compatibility -> Check All

**EDIT**

Try with processinfo

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\xxx.exe");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Security warning - if you do this, anyone who can see the window and run a program can gain LocalSystem access.

Comment: looks like you may have to enable it, in programs and features and IIS

Comment: Hi, Andrew, I did check what you said and now the IIS Admin Service is showing up. I also did check the box "Allow service to interact with desktop" then stop and restart IIS, the window still didn't call up yet.

Comment: what User Name is the xxx.exe running under?

Comment: I add <identity impersonate="true" 
  userName="administrator" 
  password="xxxxx" /> to my web.cofig but didn't work yet...

Comment: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name is "administrator".

Comment: But the xxx.exe's User Name is "SYSTEM" by Windows Task Manager

Comment: I tried this step too but it didn't work for me.